# Framerate-independent sine wave pattern

Tags: java, libgdx, frame-rate, trigonometry

What is the proper way to implement framerate-independent oscillation? I am using the LibGDX  library which provides delta time for the update loop.

Currently, my sine wave pattern works as expected as long as the FPS is at a healthy 60 average (May have skewed slightly, due to slight gif-capture software lag):

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcKmX.gif

However, when the framerate drops, the pattern becomes skewed and acts rather strangely:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn82J.gif

Here is the sine wave method:

```
private void sineWaveDown(float speed, float amplitude, boolean mirror, float delta){
    HitBox hitBox = getTransform().getHitBox();

    int mirrored = 1;
    if (mirror)
        mirrored = -1;

    Vector2 current = new Vector2(hitBox.x, hitBox.y);

    current.y -= speed * delta;
    current.x += MathUtils.sin(current.y * delta) * amplitude * mirrored;

    hitBox.setPosition(current);
}
```

In this example, `speed` is 60 and `amplitude` is 2.

`HitBox` is derived from `com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle`, and is used to logically represent the circles you see in the images above.

---

**Edit**: Question has been answered. Here is my working code:

```
private void sineWaveDown(float delta){
    HitBox hitBox = getTransform().getHitBox();

    int mirrored = 1;
    if (config.mirrored)
        mirrored = -1;

    Vector2 current = new Vector2(hitBox.x, hitBox.y);

    current.y -= config.speed * delta;

    elapsedTime = (elapsedTime + delta) % (1/config.frequency);
    float sinePosition = mirrored * config.amplitude * MathUtils.sin(MathUtils.PI2 * config.frequency * elapsedTime + config.phase);
    current.x = config.spawnPosition.x + sinePosition;

    hitBox.setPosition(current);
}
```

Comment: Im not certain here but i think your `delta` should be multiplied outside the `MathUtils.sin(current.y * delta)`. When its inside your actually altering the length of the sin wave by the FPS

Comment: This certainly crossed my mind, and I have experimented with using delta differently. If delta is used outside of the `sin` function, the circles drop down in a straight line. The delta time is between 0.01 and 0.02 with a healthy frame rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a good way to do this without using elapsed time. You can "clean" the elapsed value with a modulus to avoid losing precision after a long time elapses.

`elapsed = (elapsed + deltaTime) % (1/FREQUENCY);`

`float sinePosition = amplitude * MathUtils.sin(MathUtils.PI2 * FREQUENCY * elapsed + PHASE);`

I'm not sure what you're doing basing the sine of x off of what y is, but you can adapt the above.

Comment: I get the same result using your formula verbatim. As the frame rate drops, the wave gets closer and closer to becoming a [straight line](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KHQEM.gif).

Comment: Are you still using `=+` instead of `=`? Can you show your code? This works fine for me. Maybe it has something to do with you trying to base your x frequency on your y position?

Comment: Yes, I am still using +=. I am no longer basing it of the y position. I have updated my question with the latest code.   Note that I removed the `% (1/FREQUENCY)` bit -- it was not making a difference.

Comment: And did you notice I'm not using `+=`? Mine is an elapsed time method, not a delta method. `% (1/FREQUENCY)` won't make a difference at first, but when your elapsed time eventually gets huge, you'll start losing precision if you don't do it. In most cases, it probably won't matter, but if you were doing something like a live wallpaper that could be running for weeks, it could be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! It works now that I am using `=` instead of `+=`, as long as I (obviously) apply the initial spawn position. I am updating my question with my full working code for reference, for others.